# graphics problem in ubuntu 22.04 on virtualbox

Tags: 22.04, graphics, virtualbox, vmware

I am having some glitches in graphics in my Ubuntu 22.04 running on VirtualBox.

[image: Correct top panel]

This is what apps on the top panel should look like but what I am getting is this:

[image: Distorted Top panel]

Why is the top panel broken like this?